# for loop ( Java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am making a guessing game for fun. For some reason, the code in the for loop never processes.  I didvided it into three parts. Please let me knowCan someone help me? I have checked and the code doesnt proceed int the for loop. I am certain there is nothing wrong with the for loop. Thanks  for your hwlp Thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class Guess {
    public static Random r = new Random();
    public static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static final String YES_S = "y";
    public static final String NO_S = "n";

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException { 
        boolean menu = true;
        boolean start = false;
        boolean end = false;
        boolean ans = true;
        boolean rand = true;

        int num = -1;

        int guessNum = -1;

        while(menu) {
             System.out.println( "Start game [ y ]:");
             String input = in.readLine();

             if(input.equals(YES_S)) {
                 menu = false;
                 start = true;
                 end = false;
             }
        }

        while(start) {
            while(ans) {
                while(rand) {
                    num = r.nextInt(11);
                    rand = false;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
                    System.out.println( " Guess a number from 0 to 10 :");
                    String input1 = in.readLine();
                    guessNum = Integer.parseInt(input1);
                    if (guessNum == num) {
                        System.out.println( " Congratulations !");
                        ans = false;
                        rand = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println( " Try again");

                    }


                }
                if(ans = true) {
                   end = true;   
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should try do less things in one method. A loop in a loop in a loop in a loop ... such code turns unmaintainable the second you close your editor. If you are programming for fun; I really recommend to read "Clean code" by Robert Martin; as programming is even more fun when one still understands his code after not touching it for a few days.

Answer (score 7):

Well, let's decompose your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 3; i++)
```

1. Start with `i = 0`
2. Perform the body while `i > 3` .... whops, do you see the problem?

Comment: Thanks. wow I didnt notic that lol

Comment: Just in case you were wondering why I recommended you to focus on the quality of your code ... exactly because that helps with such kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
```

The guard condition is never true - `0 > 3` is false immediately, so the loop never runs.

Use `i < 3` as the guard instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have i>3 and i=0... 0 is not greater than 3. So, this is wrong! Change to this:

```
               for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    System.out.println( " Guess a number from 0 to 10 :");
                    String input1 = in.readLine();
                    guessNum = Integer.parseInt(input1);
                    if (guessNum == num) {
                        System.out.println( " Congratulations !");
                        ans = false;
                        rand = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println( " Try again");

                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that  `if(ans = true) {` is an assigment and not a check condition

if you want to check the value of ans do

```
if(ans == true) {
```

**OR EVEN BETTER**

```
if(ans) {
```

---

the other reason why is not working is because this:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
```

the condition is never met

do instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

Comment: I am sorry but I dont get what you mean? I am a noob :/

Comment: This isn't the only problem

Comment: If you write this: **ans == true** you are asking "if ans value is true", but when you do **ans = true** you are setting the var ans to true....

Answer (score 0):

Flip your comparison operator:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks. wow I didnt notic that lol